# Computer desk vibrates and hits wall while I type, need solution?

Tags: woodworking, desk, mount

Like the title says, when I type on my computer desk, my computer desk vibrates and hits against my wall. I was thinking about mounting L-brackets to the bottom of the desk to the studs in my wall, but I feel like there has to be some solution for this.

The desk I'm using is: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B075HBQSTC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075HBQSTC)

The floor that the desk is on is some laminate wood flooring that has a couple weak spots so that might be contributing to the desk not being as stable and moving a lot when I type.

P.S. I live in a rental so I'm not able to make any MAJOR changes, but I'm willing to hear out anyone with any advice.

Comment: Move it away from the wall ??

Comment: @AlaskaMan - he did say it is just a rental - don't get carried away with the changes.

Comment: Haha. Thanks, and I'm sorry for not mentioning it. But if I move it away from the wall, then the things I have attached to my desk (like camera mount, and mic boom arm) shake a lot whenever I type on the keyboard. 

When I put the desk against the wall, that seemed to allay some of the vibration issues with the things attached to my desk.

Answer (score 1):

It's either that all the feet are not taking equal load or the table has slack in the connections. If it's the feet issue, the plastic feet ARE adjustable, they are screwed in and you unscrew them to make a leg longer. If that issue is ruled out then it's the connections of the table, it simply isn't built to tight enough tolerances. Then, attaching to the wall is working solution.

Comment: As it is a rental the attaching to a wall is perhaps not a good idea as paying for damage on leaving can be expensive...

Comment: Definitely something to consider and evaluate. All rental contacts that I have had over the years (many!) have always allowed for incidental holes in the walls for hanging pictures and even shelves, they all allow holes up to 1/4" in diameter as classified under reasonable wear and tear and therefore not a repair items thus not the responsibility of the renter. In fact, where I live it would be against the law to charge or withhold a deposit for that RW&T. Everywhere is different though. I always patch my walls when I leave, if the landlord has played responsibly nice.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from Ack's suggestion would be to jack up two of the legs (front pair) to cause the table to cant rearward. The amount should be the minimum necessary to get the edge of the table to rest against the wall.

Place a gel pack of some sort between the wall and the table edge. I have a gel mouse pad which is overkill for this type of application. Even a silicone mat with sufficient bounce would absorb the vibration from typing and may also be easier to find.

Amazon has [pet food mats](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XZ5KP4L) which appear to be well suited:

[image: pet food mat]

as they are relatively thin, but thick enough to absorb the vibration. Use tape to attach the mat to the desktop and let it hang over the edge. You could get away without shimming the table legs if the mat is soft enough.

Comment: Hmmm, I never thought about the silicon or gel pads/mats. That seems like a really good idea if I can find something that works. I would think that something gel would work the best.

But like you both recommended, I'll try heightening the front two legs so the desk kind of leans back and see if that helps with the stability.

Comment: I was going to suggest a putty like blu-tack  but this seems better

Comment: Don't use Blu-tack. They leave a residue that I haven't figured out how to remove.